# component projection function $p_{i}$ & componentwise convergence example/explanation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

$(1)$ I usually ask about actual problems, but this is to better understand the ***ith component projection function***, $p_{i}$:$\mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined in my textbook (Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick) by

> $p_{i}(\vec{u}) \equiv u_{i}$ for $\vec{u} = (u_{1},...u_{n})$.

$(2)$ There is also a definition of ***componentwise convergence***:

> A sequence of points $ \{ \vec{u_{k}} \}$ is said to *converge
>   componentwise* to the point $\vec{u}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ provided that
>   for each index $i$ with $1 \leq i \leq n$, we have $\lim_{k\to\infty} p_{i}(\vec{u_{k}}) =
> p_{i}(\vec{u})$

**Sadly, Fitzpatrick doesn't have any examples of either of these two ideas. A simple example and/or explanation of $(1)$ and $(2)$ would be helpful.**

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec x \equiv (10, 20, 30)$, then $p_1(\vec x) = 10$, $p_2(\vec x) = 20)$, $p_3(\vec x) = 30$.

In general, such projection functions are useful to write complex expressions involving derivatives. So rather than saying "take the i'th component of $f(x)$, one simply writes $p_i \circ f$

Consider a sequence of vectors $\vec v_k \equiv (1/k, 1 + k/i)$. In this case, note that $p_1(\vec v_k) = 1/k$, and $p_2(\vec v_k) = 1 + 2/i$.

We can check that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} p_1(\vec v_k) = 0$, and $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} p_2(\vec v_k)  = 1$. Hence, we can state that the sequence of vectors $\{v_k\}$ converges componentwise to the vector $\vec u \equiv (0, 1)$, as $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} p_1(\vec v_k) = 0 = p_1(\vec u)$, and similarly $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} p_2(\vec v_k) = 1 = p_2(\vec u)$

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my question to include one more idea—componentwise convergence. Could you also explain/give an example of this as well?

Comment: Sure, I'll add that as well. In general, please create separate questions, though :)